# Can I use my Macbook Air as a second monitor for my PC?

Tags: windows-10, mac, display

I have a PC and I generally keep my Macbook Air on my desk next to it. The Macbook is generally closed, but if I could use it as a second monitor that would be awesome. Is there any hardware or software I could use to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Some macs have something called target display mode which allows for exactly what you are asking, but it requires specific hardware that I think is found just in the thunderbolt iMac. There are tools that let you turn it into a display, but they are very janky and performance is a bit of a disappointment: https://avatron.com/get-air-display/

There are tools that allow you to control your laptop with one keyboard and mouse if that's an acceptable workaround: http://symless.com/synergy/

Answer (score 0):

Some software exists. For example, I like "Spacedesk" (spacedesk.net, also available on the Microsoft Store), a program you can use to do exactly what you ask. Its advantage is that it uses HTML5, so you can stream your second screen to any HTML5 browser, so there is a huge variety of devices you can use including your MacBook. The general setup is that you would install such a program on your host (main PC), then you would stream the second screen to your client device with the HTML5 viewer. In short, it is definitely possible through streaming. I believe there is no way to input PC display directly into the MacBook Air. I hope this answers your question.

Link to spacedesk (Microsoft Store): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/spacedesk/9nblggh4trm4?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Answer (score 0):

[Deskreen](https://deskreen.com) could be an option, but you might also need something called a *display dummy plug* in order to trick your main system to think there is a second monitor plugged in.