# Is there a way to use Macbook Air as a second monitor for my PC running Windows 11?

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook, windows-11

I have a PC running Windows 11 and I have an "Early 2015" Macbook Air running Big Sur. I don't actually use the Macbook Air so I'd love to turn it into my second monitor to screen some applications. I do know there's a [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1121210/can-i-use-my-macbook-air-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-pc) about that. However, the solutions are similar to any desk which use your IP Addresses and such and I am afraid that it might be slow for some extreme uses. I want the Macbook Air to act as an actual dummy monitor which does nothing but acts as a second screen. Is there anyway I could achieve this? I can switch the Macbook Air to Windows or even Linux of any distro, if needed, but I have never done that and I have found nothing that guides this.

I do have a thunderbolt adapter with VGA ready, and I have tried to connect it to the PC but I think Macbook Air will need some sort of tuning since it won't know itself as a second monitor.

Comment: No. The linked question covers some ways of achieving this as a software/network service. That's the only way. Your Mac's display connections are all *inputs* not outputs. The only other option would be getting an additional video input device but it would be cheaper & easier to just buy a new budget display.

Comment: The best you can do is the methods mentioned in the duplicates but with a service more geared towards gaming. I've managed to get Nvidia Gamestreaming to work with Windows Remote Desktop so you may want to look for alternatives that work on a Mac. These services are the best you will get, nothing on a Mac is designed to take video in unless you buy a capture card or some such.